# How to squeeze an outlined character?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, cs5, resize

I have a text I transformed into outlines and now I would like to squeeze some characters (an "O" and a "D" specifically), so that they become less rounded, more rectangular. If I try to resize them, the path becomes thinner, but what I want to do is to squeeze them AND keep the path width the same.

Is there any way to achieve this, other than cutting the paths, move them in the desired position and turn them into a compound path again?

I am using Illustrator CS5.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and inelegant solution would be to squeeze them, then add an outline to the shapes to get them back to the same width as the other characters. You could then outline the stroke and add it to the letter shape in Pathfinder to combine it into one vector object.

A more elegant solution would be to manually adjust anchor points, but this requires an intimate knowledge of the letterform's structure to do it well.

Comment: Oh well, manually adjusting anchor points would be too tiring a business, I guess I'll stick to my first idea of cut-move-merge. Thank you for your suggestion.